# PHP replace string using overlapping regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, overlapping

### How to replace string using overlapping regular expressions?

Hello! Im trying to add html tags into string. Im using function preg_replace(), but when my patterns in array are overlaped the preg_replace doesn't work.

```
$string = 'abc';
$patterns[0] = '/a/';
$patterns[1] = '/abc/';
$replacements[0] = '<b>$0</b>';
$replacements[1] = '<i>$0</i>';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

This produce the following output:

```
<b>a</b>bc
```

But i expected this output:

```
<b><i>a</b>bc</i>
```

It seems like preg_replace takes first pattern and replace it with first replacement and then search for second pattern but it search in **modified** string.
I must use functions which **support regular expressions**.

Comment: You do realise that `<b><i>a</b>bc</i>` is invalid markup? You'd need `<i><b>a</b>bc</i>` to be valid!

Comment: Yes I do, thats not the problem

Comment: Well part of the problem is that regexp isn't the right tool for the job, DOM is the right tool

Comment: @vks that's not the solution, i get 1 or more regex, which may or may not define the same language

Comment: @MarkBaker could you explain how to use DOM tool for this?

Comment: This doesn't look like a good realistic [mcve]. Very obviously `a` will be unconditionally found when `abc` is found -- so you can make one pass over the string and make the nested tag replacement.   Perhaps show a truer sample so that we can give better advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because they don't run simultaneously, but in loop. And after first expression you end up with `<b>a</b>bc` so there is no more any `abc` for second expression to match.

It's simply as that. And that's good, because thanks to that you <del>won't end with invalid markup</del>. You will. Regex is serious problem with HTML or XML.

Use some DOM interpreter and library, like PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Could you explain how to use DOM library in PHP to this? I have never heard about it...